# Delphi - How do I initialize a TArray of String?

Tags: android, ios, arrays, string, delphi

I'm looking for a better way to initialize my `lst_devices : TArray<String>` variable.

Today, I'm doing it like this (which is very ugly and it's a code smell, but it works fine at least).

```
lst_devices_id := ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
```

How can I improve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strings are default initialized to the empty string. So you could rely on that like so:

```
SetLength(lst_devices_id, N);
```

Here you allocate the desired number of elements for the array and rely on the compiler to default initialize them to the empty string. Note that this relies on the array being previously uninitialized. If that it not the case then you would have to finalize it first.

```
Finalize(lst_devices_id);
SetLength(lst_devices_id, N);
```

Comment: Isn't "lst_devices_id := nil;" more elegant then using low level function as Finalize?

Comment: @ZENsan Finalize is an intrinsic that does the exact same thing. It is a high level function in the sense that you are expected to use it from your code and it is not intended only for internal RTL code. Take your pick.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. That's why asked, to make it clear for me.

Comment: Thank you David. I wish I could vote +2 for the `Finalize` function that I never had heard before :)

Comment: I'm sure you can find other worthy answers of mine if you so desire!!  ;-)